# Issue with image download using node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file

I am trying to download an image .I have been able to successfully store an image in my folder on server and the image details in my mongodb collection . I want to download the image when user clicks on download button on the frontEnd . I have added a route on my backend side which works well here it is my localhost is 8080....

```
    app.get('/download/', function(req, res){
      var file ='./uploads/2021-08-14T08-07-50.126Z-sample.pdf';
      var filename = path.basename(file);
      var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
      res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
      var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
      filestream.pipe(res);
       });
```

Below is a screenshot of front end

[image]

Above file data is dynamic I am getting it from my backend using fetch.

Now what I want is when when a download button is clicked I want to append the file name in the url parameter for example....

fetch(`localhost:8080/download/${file.name}`,{method:"GET"})

so that I can use the passed variable in the parameter to download the selected file which has been selected by the user in the front end.

For example:

```
  app.get('/download/', function(req, res){
  var file =`./uploads/${req.params.filename}`;
  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
   });
```

The solution I get which is working in my frontend is

```
function download(name) {
 return fetch(`http://localhost:8080/download/${name}`,{method:"GET",})
  .then(res => res.blob())
    .then( blob => {
      const file = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.location.assign(file);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using express, something like this should work.

```
app.get('/download/:filename', function(req, res){
  var file =`./uploads/${req.params.filename}`;
  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

I also advise you to use const instead of var, because none of these variables are being used outside scope and are not being reasigned

```
app.get('/download/:filename', function(req, res){
  const file =`./uploads/${req.params.filename}`;
  const filename = path.basename(file);
  const mimetype = mime.lookup(file);
  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
  const filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

For the problem with fetch you having you can use this code:

```
const file = filename.split(".")
const mime = file[file.length - 1] // get the last index

  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': `image/${mime}`
    },
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'
  }).then((image) => {

    const imageBlog = await image.blob()
    const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlog)

    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = imageURL

    link.download = 'image file name here'
    document.body.appendChild(link)

    link.click()
    document.body.removeChild(link)

  });
```

Test it and tell me if it works, change the variable names too

Comment: I said that because var are stored globally, for something that will be discarded after its downloaded you don't need to hold that info on the global scope, that's just best practices.

Comment: I am able to call the endpoint from my frontend with the code you had provided. But I have another issue when I make a download request through my frontend using fetch I dont get the downloaded file and in the response tab I get something very weird. When I hit the endpoint directly by providing the file name in the URL i get the downloaded file.Can you help.I can share my code with you.

Comment: Make sure you have GET method on your fetch, fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET'
}

Comment: Ima edit my question with a example code for the fetch

Comment: finished the code, please have a test and tell me if it works

Comment: Thanks for you time and solution I have already found the solution and its working as expected...

Comment: I am updating my question with the frontend code in working condition so you can check and it might be a help for someone in the future